# Modify size of the map for export

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

I want to export my map on a different size. The only way I've found to get the export clean is to set a new height and width to my map before calling the export function, like this function for example :

```
canvas.resizeAndExport = function(canvas){
                document.getElementById('ol3map').style.width = '569px';
                document.getElementById('ol3map').style.height = '238px';
                olmap.updateSize();
                return canvas.toDataURL();
            }
```

But it changes the size of the map on the screen (obviously). And that's the point, I don't want my user to see the change.

How can I do that? Cloning my map?

Comment: You may want to have a look at http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/export-pdf.html - it does more or less what you suggested. The map is set back to its original dimensions after the export, so users usually do not notice much of the temporary size change.

Comment: @ahocevar Thanks that exactly what I need, I only noticed the export png example, my bad.